# PHP Active Session Warning in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I know this question is frequently asked on this forum, but none of the proposed solutions has worked for me, basically, I am a WordPress plugin developer and developing a plugin whose session starts in the init file but close when the client closes his/her browser, and it is necessary to keep the session open. In this case, how can I get rid of this warning? Maybe I should use something other than the session or what you suggest.

Till now there are different proposed solutions like Use

```
if ( !session_id() ) {
session_start( [
    'read_and_close' => true,
] );
```

}

but with this technique, I can never be able to use sessions in my plugin, and the whole functionality goes on the ground.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: _"how can I get rid of this warning"_ - what warning? Please quote error messages _verbatim_.

Comment: @cBroe here is the warning
1. A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

2. The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress plugin or theme developers cannot use php's [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) subsystem as you have discovered.

If you need to save some kind of global context for your plugin to work, use WordPress's [add_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) function to save it at the end of each operation. You can retrieve your context using [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

If you need per-user context, use [add_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) to save it and [get_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) to retrieve it.  Like this:

```php
$id = get_current_user_id();
$myContext = get_user_meta( $id, 'my_plugins_meta_tag_name' );
...
add_user_meta( $id, 'my_plugins_meta_tag_name', $myContext);
```

WordPress uses a database table to store these sorts of options. Some sites put an object cache in front of the table. But these APIs are how you do what you want to do.

In your plugin's deactivation hook, please consider calling [delete_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_option/) to clean up that storage. And, if you use per-user context, please consider using [delete_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_user_meta/) to remove your user_meta item from all of them.

```php
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user){
    delete_user_meta ( $user->ID, 'my_plugins_meta_tag_name' );
}
```

As for sensitive information, WordPress offers no other place to put it. And, if you were using sessions, php would need to put it somewhere as well. By default, php puts session data in the filesystem of the server.  That's why WordPress [hashes user passwords](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/) before storing them.

Comment: @Jones thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking the same thing but is it recommended that save sensitive information in the WP options?

Comment: Thank you so much @O.Jones for the detailed answer.